# Applying the SUM of a FILTER to all rows in the sheet (like using ARRAYFORMULA)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula which produces the correct value for a single row, as follows:
`=SUM(FILTER(otherSheet!C2:C, otherSheet!B2:B=B2))`

I would like to auto-fill this formula across every row. To do this, I would need to replace the "B2" at the end of the formula with something like B2:B. However, the only two ways I can think of doing this (apart from dragging the cell handle down the entire spreadsheet) don't produce the desired effect.

I've tried: `=SUM(FILTER(otherSheet!C2:C, otherSheet!B2:B=B2:B))` and `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(FILTER(otherSheet!C2:C, otherSheet!B2:B=B2:B)))` - but neither work (in fact, they just prodce the first cell where `otherSheet!B2:B=B2` - for reasons that I almost understand but can't quite work though in my head)

How would I produce the desired effect, i.e. the original formula but with the final `B2` expanded so that as you go down the sheet it is applied to B3, B4, B5, etc.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Sheet is confidential. I could create a dummy, but anyone could given the simplified parameters I put in the example.

Answer (score 3):

Try using SUMIF formula:

[image]

Fact that columns are in different sheets should have no effect here.

My soulution is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LwWPFtBL9hjor_HS2U__jIKeZbudMz-ZDJsXAQ0mjiU/copy

Reference: [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583)

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be better answers, but this worked.  Formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2:B4,
  ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(UNIQUE(
    ARRAYFORMULA(otherSheet!B1:B&"~"&SUMIF(otherSheet!B$1:B,otherSheet!B1:B,otherSheet!C$1:C))),"~",1)),2,0))
```

This basically adds the field value from column B with a sum of the values in column C, giving a repeating table of values like this:

FieldB~149

Field~10

FieldB~149

Field~10

It then takes the unique subset of these values, splits them back into a "field and sum of values" table, which is then used by a `VLOOKUP` inside an arrayformula, to find your summed value for the fields in column B of your main sheet.

You can add an `IFERROR` wrapper to remove the error that shows if there is no matching value from column B in the data range for the VLOOKUP.

[image]

The data in otherSheet looks like this:

[image]